# Source for GeoJSON data for the US

Tags: data, geojson, united-states

Does anyone know of any good sources for US data (counties, congressional districts, etc) in GeoJSON format? Has anyone converted public-domain shapefiles/sources to GeoJSON that they would be willing to share?

Comment: If you acquire the datasets there's always the possibility to converted them yourself through ogr2ogr utility in the GDAL library or with QGIS (which uses the GDAL library).

Comment: @PedroMendes Thanks for the suggestion. That is why I've been doing. I was just curious if there was a more comprehensive source for US data.

Comment: Not much US data but I was super happy to find [geojson.xyz](http://geojson.xyz), since they have a simple index of a wide variety of data sources, all hosted on Cloudfront with CORS headers so I can test out my application on a bunch of primitive types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found something closer to what I was looking for (US State and County boundaries) on github: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA

The features are very generalized/simplified, but they'll work for a national scale map. Country boundaries for the whole world are available in this repo too.

Answer (score 6):

After trying to find similar GeoJSON versions of US State and County boundaries, I finally decided to roll my own from the United States [Census Cartographic Boundary Files](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.html), converting them to GeoJSON and KML formats using the [MyGeoData vector converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/).

I've made the results of this conversion available at: https://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/. Feel free to use these if they will help.

Comment: Was using these, gratefully, but just noticed that California districts are not accurate for 113th Congress. For instance, in http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_500_11_20m.json look in the northern part of the state. Not sure of accuracy other states.

Comment: @MarjorieRoswell, can you tell whether the source data was the issue, or is there a problem with only the JSON?

Comment: I just downloaded, unzipped, and checked gz_2010_us_050_00_20m.zip: It's using the older districts, too. Here's what CA should look like for the current congress: http://nationalatlas.gov/printable/printableViewer.htm?imgF=images/preview/congdist/pagecgd113_ca.gif&imgW=792&imgH=612

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Marjorie. I'm not surprised that redistricting is not fully reflected in these 2010 files. But it is good to be alert about this lag.

Comment: Use TIGER2013 to get the congressional districts (and state legislative districts) as they were redrawn after the 2010 census. http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/

Answer (score 4):

I've translated most of the Census Cartography files to GeoJSON for your convenience:

https://github.com/loganpowell/census-geojson

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [SimpleGeo’s CC0 Places data set](http://blog.simplegeo.com/2011/08/01/august-updates/), and this related question: [Converting SimpleGeo Places GeoJSON file to shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/converting-simplegeo-places-geojson-file-to-shapefile)

or just searching the [geojson tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geojson) may turn up some results for you.

Comment: January 12th, 2012: After SimpleGeo was acquired by Urban Airship in Oct 2011, Urban Aiship said “wind down the availability of the current versions of [SimpleGeo's] Places, Context, and Storage over the next few months.”...The target date for pulling the plug officially will be March 31, 2012. [Link](http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/12/urban-airship-to-shutter-simplegeo-services-in-march-with-factual-picking-up-the-slack/)

Answer (score 2):

****Disclaimer, I work for this company****

you can get US Zipcode Boundaries(qurey by city,state,or county)[image] via this api API:
https://boundaries-io.com

the  API shows US Boundaries(GeoJson) by zipcode,city, and state.
you should use the API programatically to handle large results.

the image is query by state(DC)..gives you all zipcodes in DC.

Comment: This uses TIGER2013, and can query for multiple counties,cities,states,zipcodes for aggregate GeoJson responses.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on linux, try converting .shp files downloaded directly from the [census website](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html) to geoJSON data using the gdal command line tool. For Debian/Ubuntu that means installing the `gdal-bin` [package](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gdal-bin), and then running a command like this one:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON cb_2018_us_cbsa_20m.json cb_2018_us_cbsa_20m.shp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Freebase API. For example the following article

http://www.freebase.com/view/en/orange_county

Available in JSON:

http://www.freebase.com/experimental/topic/standard/en/orange_county