# Touristic poi-data (api or dump) with popularity measure?

Tags: data, point-of-interest

I'm looking for freely available touristic (hotel, restaurants, bars, attractions, etc.) poi-data that have some measure of popularity.

With popularity I mean, explicit popularity like on Tripadvisor (i.e: #10 out of 1500 attractions in Paris), but no api/ dump is available for TA. Or otherwise more soft-measures like the nr of checkins (Foursquare for example)

Anyone knows of any data-set (dump or api) which makes this type of info available? First use would be to display markers on a map, where only the most popular are shown. (as showing all 5000 available bars in say Paris is not very practical)

See list below of some sources I'm checking out

- Factual Global PLaces (dataset from former SimpleGeo): likely no popularity, not tried.
- openstreetmap (not tried yet, perhaps my next check)
- foursquare (has an api with implicit popularity (nr of checkins)) but hard/impossible to query the api to get complete coverage (besides it's against their ToS
- Facebook Graph api looking for places (not tried)

Comment: Have a look on this thread
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/converting-simplegeo-places-geojson-file-to-shapefile

Comment: Did you solve the problem. If yes, how ?

Comment: I think this is a question that would be better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.