# GeoJSON to shapefile conversion with GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, java, geojson, geotools

Can someone please provide me an example of how to convert GeoJSON to shapefile using GeoTools?

Comment: may be useful for you http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/converting-simplegeo-places-geojson-file-to-shapefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed the resource pointed out by @iant and..
Here's the solution:

```
public static void toShp(File geojson) throws IOException {     
    File shpFile = new File("test.shp");
    ShapefileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new ShapefileDataStoreFactory();

    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    params.put("url", shpFile.toURI().toURL());
    params.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);

    ShapefileDataStore shpDataStore = (ShapefileDataStore)  dataStoreFactory.createNewDataStore(params);


    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(geojson);
    int decimals = 15; 
    GeometryJSON gjson = new GeometryJSON(decimals); 
    FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON(gjson);

    FeatureCollection fc = fjson.readFeatureCollection(in);

    SimpleFeatureType type = (SimpleFeatureType) fc.getSchema();        
    shpDataStore.createSchema(type);

    Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");

    String typeName = shpDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

    SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = shpDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    if (featureSource instanceof FeatureStore) {
        SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;

        featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
        try {

            featureStore.addFeatures(fc);

            transaction.commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            transaction.rollback();

        } finally {
            transaction.close();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(typeName + " does not support read/write access");
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a precanned example of this but you should be able to work out the basics from the cvs to shapefile example [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html).
There is an [unsupported GeoJSON module](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/unsupported/geojson.html) that should also be of help.